# Div expanding to max-width even when it can't fit another element on that line

Tags: html, css

When the browser displaying the code below is resized, the `div` is expanding to `max-width` when I don't want it to.

If everything fits on 1 line it looks fine, but when I shrink the size of the browser (pushing the `img`'s onto 2 lines) there is now extra space in the `div` to the right of the last image on the first line. I would like the `div` **to not expand** to `max-width` if it can't fit another `img` on the line (and instead have the `div` width end at the end of the rightmost `img` in the `div`).

Test code:

```css
.parent {
  background: red;
  max-width: 90%;
  display: inline-block;
}
img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link href="test.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="parent">
    <img src="" />
    <img src="" />
    <img src="" />
    <img src="" />
    <img src="" />
    <img src="" />
    <img src="" />
    <img src="" />
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: If you specify `max-width:90%` then it will take `90%` of parent, in your case `90%` of `<body>`. specify `width` explicitly in `px`

Comment: @Rohit Thanks, if all the img's already fit on one line and I make the browser bigger it will not continue to expand to 90% (it will be less than 90%). Is there any way to do it using CSS so that I don't have to calculate specific pixel widths and the CSS will take care of it when resizing

Answer (score 0):

Try to do `width:fit-content` or `width` of `auto` or set a `min-width` too

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve this type of behavior, use img width to auto and the container to 100%. But now your image will get stretched without keeping the right side white space.

You can use media query if it is make sense and control your image width based on the custom screen size.

Comment: I was hoping to keep the images the same size, but just to shrink the div a little bit down from 90% when there was extra red space on the right

Answer (score 0):

Here try this Set the `min-width` to `fit-content` or you can set the max-width to `fit-content` or `auto` the reason why you have that extra is because the width is 90% and you img blocks are to big for that space try bringing your width down some try doing `width: 87.4%;`

Comment: Thank you but using fit-content or auto I still got extra red space on the right when I resized the browser. I am hoping to never have any extra red space on the right no matter how I resize the browser. Using a specific width won't with all the different screen sizes.